# Bash Find Function Ubuntu - Find in directory tree, files that have the same name as their directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find

I want to find and print files in directory tree, that have the sname name as theirs dirs.

This is my code so far:

```
#!bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No args"
fi

if [[ -d $1 ]] #if its dir
then
    find $1 -type f | (while read var1 #for every regular file in dir tree
        do

        if [[ -f $var1 ]] 
        then
            echo $var1 #full path
            # I dont know how to get the dir name
            echo $(basename $var1) #file name
            echo

#then compare it and print full path
        fi
    done)
fi
```

I want to do this using FIND function in bash linux. Thanks

Comment: FWIW, find is not a function, it's an external command, typically placed at `/usr/bin/find`; (unless you define a function by that name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script with `find`:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
   d="${f%/*}"
   [[ ${d##*/} == ${f##*/} ]] && echo "$f"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```